# remove method sorted dictionary java

Tags: java, dictionary

I am trying to write the remove method of an sorted dictionary using the binary search method. My dictionary is a position-list, sequenced based dictionary. The search method is as follows:

```
private Entry<Integer, V> binarySearch(int key, int low, int high) {
    int mid = (high + low) / 2;
    if(low > high){
        return null;
    }
    else if(sortedList.get(mid).getKey() == key){
        return sortedList.get(mid);
    }
    else if(sortedList.get(mid).getKey() > key){
        return binarySearch(key, low, mid-1);
    }
    else{
        return binarySearch(key, mid+1, high);
    }
}
```

My code so far is:

```
@Override
public Entry<Integer, V> remove(Entry<Integer, V> e)
        throws InvalidEntryException { 
if(e == null){
    throw new InvalidEntryException("");
}
Entry<Integer, V> entry = binarySearch(e.getKey(), 0, size());
if(entry != e){
    boolean found = false;
    int i = getLocation(entry.getKey());
    while(!found && i < size()-1){
        entry = binarySearch(e.getKey(), i+1, size());
        if(entry == e){
            found = true;
            sortedList.remove(i);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
else{
    sortedList.remove(getLocation(entry.getKey()));
}
if(entry == null){
    throw new InvalidEntryException("");
}
else{
    return entry;
}
}
```

Can anyone help with any input at all? I'm not really sure how to go about this and I am beyond frustrated. I basically need to remove if the entry is the same instance as the parameter. As with a dictionary, there could be multiple entries with the same key but I need to remove ONLY IF the entry is the same instance as the param.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> there could be multiple entries with the same key but I need to remove ONLY IF the entry is the same instance as the param.

You are confused about equality of instances in java. You'll need to override the [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method and define how the equality operates over your objects. With this you also need to look at [`hashcode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

And the instance you are trying to compare can never be as the same instance as that of param passed.

Comment: No I understand. I do not want to override the equals method. I am instructed to use the == operator not change equals()